# how can i get followers member by sql

Tags: php, sql

I have a table in the database named members

and i have a field in this table named following

this field contains the data  like this

```
,marck,nancy,sarah
```

when i  get following i use this code

```
$select_me = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  members where username='admin'");
$rows_me = $select_me->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);

$following_me = $rows_me['following'];

$ar_member = explode(",",$following_me);
$name_follwing = implode("','",$ar_member)."";

$select_following = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username IN ('$name_follwing')");
$num_following = $select_following->num_rows;

echo $num_following;
```

How can i get member followers by sql ?

thanks

Comment: Did you design this table?

Comment: [Normalise your DB](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/mysqlDatabaseDesignNormalisation.htm).

Comment: what does $num_following return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should redesign the table so that names field is its own child table, e.g. normalize the design. Failing that, you can TEMPORARILY work around it with mysql's [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM members
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('admin', following) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the `count` e.g:

```
$ar_member = explode(",",$following_me);
echo "total followers : ".count(array_filter($ar_member));
```

Answer (score -1):

implements a query with count ()

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: -1 for not linking to the mysql documentation, and -infinity for using [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)